# Can a CryptoNote coin be merge mined with a non-CryptoNote coin?

Tags: cryptonote, cryptonight, merge-mining

If the CryptoNight algorithm was replaced with say, SHA-256, could it be merge mined with bitcoin, for example?

The prior [merge mining question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/369/can-any-cryptonote-coins-be-merge-mined) is about mining with other CryptoNote networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the cryptonight algorithm was replaced with say, sha256, could it be merge mined with bitcoin, for example?

That would certainly be possible. The requirements for merged mining basically boil down to (i) having the same PoW algorithm and (ii) miners of both chains agreeing to merge mine.

More information about the specifics of merged mining can be found [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/273/how-does-merged-mining-work).

Comment: in the repository, where would this change be made?

Comment: The CryptoNight steps are described [here](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c#L543) in the code, so I guess mostly there.